# Defining many constants

Tags: php, class-constants

I have to declare about 300 constants and was wondering if there is any faster, better way than to write each one out individually.

```
    const CHANNEL1              = "G";
    const CHANNEL2              = "U";
    const CHANNEL3              = "E";
    const CHANNEL4              = "I";
```

ETC.. all the way to const CHANNEL300

Comment: Write a script that does it for you. Of course, that may take equally as long....

Comment: @JohnConde Or, longer! ;)

Comment: Having lots of variables or constants with numeric suffixes usually indicates poor design. They should be an array. And if it's a bunch of characters, maybe it should be a single string, which you access by position.

Comment: Where do all these constants come from, maybe it should be a function that calculates them.

Comment: its just a temporary fix until we make it dynamic. Scope would be to large for this release and this is just a quick fix for the meantime

Comment: what is the relationship between the constant name and the value. What would be next in the series?

Comment: also these are class constants, I dont think you can create a function that will make these as they are hard coded

Comment: The constants are for 2 channels , I need 100 facebook ad and 100 google ad constants.